# Need to change particles color when mouse move by THREE JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I have a particle image that made from shader texture and i need the color that  `gl_FragColor.rgb = texture.rgb;` animate to change color like a weather forecast map or rotate color change.

my scene.js

```
import {
  Color,
  WebGLRenderer,
  Scene,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  AxesHelper,
  BufferGeometry,
  BufferAttribute,
  Points,
  ShaderMaterial,
  Raycaster,
  Vector2,
  Vector3,
} from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
import Stats from 'stats-js'
import LoaderManager from '@/js/managers/LoaderManager'
import GUI from 'lil-gui'

import vertexShader from '@/js/glsl/main.vert'
import fragmentShader from '@/js/glsl/main.frag'
import { randFloat } from 'three/src/math/MathUtils'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import TouchTexture from './TouchTexture'
import { isTouch } from '@/js/utils/isTouch'

export default class MainScene {
  canvas
  renderer
  scene
  camera
  controls
  stats
  width
  height
  customMaterial

  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.querySelector('.scene')

    this.touch = new TouchTexture()

    this.init()
  }

  init = async () => {
    const assets = [
      {
        name: 'background',
        texture: './img/image.jpg',
      },
    ]

    await LoaderManager.load(assets)

    this.setStats()
    this.setScene()
    this.setRender()
    this.setCamera()
    // this.setControls()
    this.setParticlesGrid()
    this.setRaycaster()

    this.handleResize()

    this.events()

    this.animateIn()
  }

  setRender() {
    this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: this.canvas,
      antialias: true,
    })
  }

  setScene() {
    this.scene = new Scene()
  }

  setCamera() {
    const aspectRatio = this.width / this.height
    const fieldOfView = 60
    const nearPlane = 0.1
    const farPlane = 10000

    this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(fieldOfView, aspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane)
    this.camera.position.y = 0
    this.camera.position.x = 0
    this.camera.position.z = 250
    this.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

    this.scene.add(this.camera)
  }


  setControls() {
    // this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement)
    // this.controls.enableDamping = true
  }

  setParticlesGrid() {
    const geometry = new BufferGeometry()

    const particles = []
    const initPositions = []
    const multiplier = 18
    const nbColumns = 16 * multiplier
    const nbLines = 9 * multiplier

    this.nbColumns = nbColumns
    this.nbLines = nbLines

    const halfColumn = nbColumns / 2
    const halfLines = nbLines / 2


    for (let i = 0; i < nbLines; i++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < nbColumns; y++) {
        const point = [i, y, 0.0]

        let initPoint = [i - halfLines, y - halfColumn, randFloat(100, 500)]

        particles.push(...point)
        initPositions.push(...initPoint)
      }
    }

    const vertices = new Float32Array(particles)
    const initPositionsFloat = new Float32Array(initPositions)

    geometry.setAttribute('position', new BufferAttribute(vertices, 3))
    geometry.setAttribute('initPosition', new BufferAttribute(initPositionsFloat, 3))

    geometry.center()

    this.dpr = 2
    this.uniforms = {
      uColor: { value: new Color(0xffffff) },
      uPointSize: { value: 1.5 },
      uTexture: { value: LoaderManager.assets['background'].texture },      
      uNbLines: { value: nbLines },
      uNbColumns: { value: nbColumns },
      uProgress: { value: 0 },
      uTime: { value: 0 },
      uTouch: { value: this.touch.texture },
      uScaleHeightPointSize: { value: (this.dpr * this.height) / 2 },
      uMouse: { value: new Vector2(0, 0) },
      uColorChange: { value: new Vector3() },

    }

    this.customMaterial = new ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: this.uniforms,
      vertexShader,
      fragmentShader,
      transparent: true,
      depthTest: false,
      depthWrite: false,
    })
    this.mesh = new Points(geometry, this.customMaterial)

    this.scene.add(this.mesh)
  }

  animateIn() {
    gsap.fromTo(
      this.uniforms.uProgress,
      {
        value: 0,
      },
      {
        value: 1,
        duration: 2.5,
        ease: 'Power4.easeOut',
      }
    )
  }

  setAxesHelper() {
    const axesHelper = new AxesHelper(3)
    this.scene.add(axesHelper)
  }


  setStats() {
    this.stats = new Stats()
    this.stats.showPanel(0)
    document.body.appendChild(this.stats.dom)
  }

  events() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize, { passive: true })
    this.draw(0)

  }

  draw = (time) => {
    this.stats.begin()

    if (this.controls) this.controls.update()
    this.uniforms.uTime.value += 0.05;

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)

    this.touch.update()

    this.stats.end()
    this.raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw)
  }

  handleResize = () => {
    this.width = window.innerWidth
    this.height = window.innerHeight

    this.camera.aspect = this.width / this.height
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(this.dpr)
    this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height)

    this.uniforms.uScaleHeightPointSize.value = (this.dpr * this.height) / 2
  }

  setRaycaster() {
    this.ray = new Raycaster()
    this.mouse = new Vector2()

    if (isTouch()) {
      window.addEventListener('touchmove', this.handleTouchMove)
    } else {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove)
    }
  }

  handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const x = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1
    const y = -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1
    this.mouse.x = x
    this.mouse.y = y

    this.ray.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera)
    this.intersects = this.ray.intersectObjects([this.mesh])

    if (this.intersects.length) {
      const uv = new Vector2(0.5, 0.5)
      uv.x = this.intersects[0].point.x / this.nbLines + 0.5
      uv.y = this.intersects[0].point.y / this.nbColumns + 0.5
      this.touch.addTouch(uv)

      const colorChange = new Vector3(x, y, 1.0);
      this.uniforms.uColorChange.value = colorChange;
      this.uniforms.uMouse.value = new Vector2(x, y);
    }


  }

  handleTouchMove = (e) => {
    const x = (e.touches[0].clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1
    const y = -(e.touches[0].clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1

    this.mouse.x = x
    this.mouse.y = y

    this.ray.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera)
    this.intersects = this.ray.intersectObjects([this.mesh])

    if (this.intersects.length) {
      const uv = new Vector2(0.5, 0.5)
      uv.x = this.intersects[0].point.x / this.nbLines + 0.5
      uv.y = this.intersects[0].point.y / this.nbColumns + 0.5
      this.touch.addTouch(uv)

      const colorChange = new Vector3(x, y, 1.0);
      this.uniforms.uColorChange.value = colorChange;
    }
  }


}
```

fragment shader

```
precision highp float;

uniform vec3 uColor;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform float uNbLines;
uniform float uNbColumns;
uniform float uProgress;
uniform float uScroll;
uniform vec3 colorChange;
uniform vec2 uMouse;
uniform vec3 uColorChange;
uniform sampler2D uTouch;

varying vec2 vTexCoords;


float circle(vec2 uv, float border) {
    float radius = 0.5;
    float dist = radius - distance(uv, vec2(0.5));
  return smoothstep(0.0, border, dist);
}

void main() {

  vec2 uv = gl_PointCoord;
  
  uv.y *= -1.;
  uv /= vec2(uNbLines, uNbColumns);
  
  float texOffsetU = vTexCoords.x / uNbLines;
  float texOffsetV = vTexCoords.y / uNbColumns;
  uv += vec2(texOffsetU, texOffsetV);
  uv += vec2(0.5);

  vec4 texture = texture2D(uTexture, uv);

  gl_FragColor.rgb = texture.rgb;

  if(gl_FragColor.r < 0.1) {
    discard;
  }

  gl_FragColor.a = 1.;
  gl_FragColor.a *= circle(gl_PointCoord, 0.2);
  gl_FragColor.a *= uProgress;
}
```

vertex shader

```
precision highp float;

uniform float uPointSize;
uniform float uProgress;
uniform sampler2D uTouch;
uniform float uTime;
uniform float uNbLines;
uniform float uNbColumns;
uniform float uScaleHeightPointSize;
attribute vec3 initPosition;
uniform vec2 uMouse;


varying vec2 vTexCoords;

const float scale = 1.0;

float random(vec2 st) {
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy, vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453123);
}

void main() {
    #include <begin_vertex>

    vec2 mouseOffset = uMouse - vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    vec3 offset = vec3(mouseOffset, 0.0);


    transformed = initPosition + ((position - initPosition) * uProgress);
    vec2 direction = transformed.xy - uMouse;

    vec2 vUv = transformed.xy / vec2(uNbLines, uNbColumns) - vec2(-0.5, -0.5);

    float touch = texture2D(uTouch, vUv).r;

    // transformed.xy += direction * touch * 0.2;

    #include <project_vertex>

    vTexCoords = position.xy;

    gl_PointSize = uPointSize * ( uScaleHeightPointSize / - mvPosition.z );
}
```